# Python 3.x - IF statements to produce a result if more than one entry field on tk is filled

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I have 4 entry fields, i want an error message to popup when more than one of these fields has an entry. Sounds simple but i cant seem to get an if statement to do what i want it to.

My current non-working code is here:-

```
        val1 = (entry1.get())
        val2 = (entry2.get())
        rval1 = (rootentry1.get())
        rval2 = (rootentry2.get())
        rval3 = (rootentry3.get())
        rval4 = (rootentry4.get())
        glthickval = (glthick.get())
        glthickvalfloat = float(glthickval)
        validation = 0
        global data

        try:
            int(val1)
            int(val2)
        except ValueError:
            message5 = 'The number must be a whole number!'
            box.showerror("Invalid Input", message5)

        if int(rval1+rval2+rval3+rval4) > 0:
            if int(rval1) and int(rval2) and int(rval3) and int(rval4) >0:
                message7 = 'You have selected more than one type of root!'
                box.showerror("Invalid Input",message7)
```

this bottom part is the part i cant get to work, clearly and and and rule will only flag if all of the values are above 0. maybe there is another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you certainly do love your brackets.

Comment: Some things never die buddy! my love for brackets is one of them! Although there isn't a single unnecessary bracket in this code.

Comment: @LMCT: There are lots of unnecessary brackets in the code. `rval1 = rootentry1.get()` is sufficient, for example.

Comment: I would also advise that you do not name variables things like `var1`, `var2`, etc. It's really not helpful in terms of the readability of the code, the mere fact that you require numbers after the variable names suggests that they are not good names for the variables.

Comment: @chepner thankyou for your advice, i did not realise the syntax would work without the brackets.

Comment: @will you might be right but this is just a small section of a much larger program, and this is my first program so making tons of variables with convoluted names makes me feel smarter than i actually am :) i should probably go through it and make things more logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose a list of all your values, filter out the ones that equal zero, and measure the length of the result.

```
values = [rval1, rval2, rval3, rval4]
filled_values = [value for value in values if int(value) != 0]
if len(filled_values) > 1:
    print "You have selected more than one type of root!"
```

---

By the way, when you have multiple variables whose names only differ by a number on the end, that's usually a good sign that you should be using a list. Consider having a single `root_entries` list, which contains your four root entry objects.

Comment: +1 for multiple variables ending in numbers. Its all about writing your code as if your future self was sitting behind you with a hammer.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of answers in here which have nice list comprehensions, and `lambda`s, and other clever stuff, but they all seem to detract on the readability of what you want to do...

I would make a small function, which tells you how many entries are filled, something like:

```
def filledEntries(entries):
  filledEntryCount = 0
  for entry in entries:
    if entry != 0: filledEntryCount += 1

  return filledEntryCount
```

and then just have something like

```
if filledEntries(entries) > 1:
  box.showerror("Invalid Input", "You have selected more than one type of root!")
```

Comment: I like it! thats rather smart, i guess this is the price of writing a program as you go to just make it work rather than properly thinking through and constructing it, i clearly am not yet thinking like a true programmer. This helps alot thankyou i would upvote you but apparently my opinion is irrelevant according to stackoverflow :P

Comment: I find it often gives much neater result if you just pretend that all of the functions you need exist right from the outset, and just throw them in, and then write the functions later.

Comment: Interesting practice, i will have to remember that one. Im sure you will be seeing more posts from me in the future as i attempt to grapple with more complex programs using python and tkinter or possibly pyside. And i look forward to your continued input :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use that i guess

```
if len(list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [rval1, rval2, rval3, rval4]))) > 1:
  # you've got more than one value that's not none
```

Comment: Lambda, hmm that might very well work, i shall have to learn how this works to see if it might solve other problems more than the current fix does. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

@LMCT, A good way to ensure that the user cannot enter into the wrong (or more than one) entry box at a time would be to disable those entry boxes until they are needed (not using an if statement but still a good solution):

```
rval1.config(state = 'disabled')
# then when needed
rval1.config(state = 'normal')
```

this can be used so that the user enters once at a time, then hits a button to submit the first entry, and to make the next entry box available. OR, if you wanted you could make another button (check/menu button or something?) for the user to select which entry box they wanted to be use-able at that time.

I thought i'd just add this anyway (even though an answer is already accepted) as it was a good solution in my opinion, and it might be handy for you!